# Why and how is it that Yoruichi can transform into a cat?

Tags: bleach

I have heard different theories like her mother was a cat demon, she has a kudo no one else has, or the cat is a really advanced gigai. I would really like to know if any of these are true and if not what is the real explanation for it?

Comment: Another theory: the cat form is her bankai. :P

Comment: I heard from my super anime otaku friend that in an interview Tite Kubo said that Yoruichi's mother was a cat demon so that is where she got her ability, but since it is "from the grapevine" I didn't know the validity of it.

Comment: `Another theory: the cat form is her bankai` Bankai obtained in years of training... imagine if ichigo's transformation _bankai_ is kon.

Answer (score 4):

There is no definitive answer to this and any attempts at an to answer this would be speculative at most. It was never explained in neither the manga nor the anime.

From the [wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Yoruichi_Shih%C5%8Din):

> ...While it is ***unknown*** how she obtained her cat transformation, she appears to prefer spending most of her time in it....

Answer (score 1):

It is never told why she can do this. But it has something to do with her leaving the Soul Society. It might have been the only way she was able to get out. She was the form of a cat for 100 years. She is the only known one to be able to do this.

Hope this helped!

Comment: The part about leaving SS in that form kinda makes sense but still speculation at most.